# How to solve "ERROR: Failed building wheel for doom-py"

Tags: python, macos, pip, openai-gym

I'm following a tutorial that requires for me to install ppaquette-gym-doom. However I keep getting an error,

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for doom-py
```

I'm on a MacBook and am using an anaconda environment in python 3.6.

I tried to install packages that the error code said I needed,

**brew install boost boost-python sdl2**

**pip install cmake**

However this didn't help fix the error. I also tried to do this on python 2.7 but it also did not work.

Here's the full error,

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for doom-py
...

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-record-kij0gfeh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/
    Complete output (137 lines):
    running install
    running build
    CMake Warning:
      No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
      same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
      become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


    -- Boost version: 1.70.0
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   filesystem
    --   thread
    --   system
    --   date_time
    --   chrono
    --   regex
    --   iostreams
    --   atomic
    CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake_modules/CreateLaunchers.cmake:48 (cmake_policy):
      The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
      of CMake.

      The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
      policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
      specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
      behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      src/vizdoom/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)


    -- Could NOT find GME (missing: GME_LIBRARIES GME_INCLUDE_DIR)
    -- Using system zlib
    -- Using system jpeg library
    -- Using system bzip2 library
    -- Using internal gme library
    -- /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
    -- /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
    -- /private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/doom_py/src/vizdoom/lzma/C
    -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
    -- Could not find FMOD include files
    -- Could NOT find MPG123 (missing: MPG123_LIBRARIES MPG123_INCLUDE_DIR)
    -- Could NOT find FluidSynth (missing: FLUIDSYNTH_LIBRARIES FLUIDSYNTH_INCLUDE_DIR)
    -- Boost version: 1.70.0
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   thread
    --   system
    --   date_time
    --   chrono
    --   atomic
    -- Fluid synth libs: FLUIDSYNTH_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
    -- Using python library: /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
    -- Using python include: /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/include/python3.6m
    CMake Warning at /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1822 (message):
      No header defined for python-py368; skipping header check
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:124 (find_package)


    -- Could NOT find Boost
    CMake Warning at /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1822 (message):
      No header defined for python-py36; skipping header check
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:133 (find_package)


    -- Could NOT find Boost
    -- Boost library python-py36:
    -- Could NOT find Boost
    -- Boost library python36:
    CMake Warning at /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1822 (message):
      No header defined for python-py3; skipping header check
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:133 (find_package)


    -- Could NOT find Boost
    -- Boost library python-py3:
    -- Could NOT find Boost
    -- Boost library python3:
    CMake Error at /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2155 (message):
      Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

      Boost version: 1.70.0

      Boost include path: /usr/local/include

      Could not find the following Boost libraries:

              boost_python

      No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
      directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
      Boost.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:151 (find_package)


    -- Found components for NumPy
    -- NUMPY_ROOT_DIR    = /usr/local
    -- NUMPY_INCLUDES    = /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include
    -- NUMPY_LIBRARIES   = /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a
    -- NUMPY_API_VERSION = 1.16.4
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/doom_py/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/doom_py/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

    Could not build doom-py: Command '['cmake', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DBUILD_PYTHON=ON', '-DBUILD_JAVA=OFF', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/bin/python', '-DOSX_COCOA_BACKEND=OFF']' returned non-zero exit status 1.. (HINT: are you sure cmake is installed? You might also be missing a library. doom_py requires boost, boost-python, sdl2 on OSX (installable via 'brew install boost boost-python sdl2')

...

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/DoomAi/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-install-hwwmtp15/doom-py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8v/645qcxqj4lzbth2zf4x8dfcm0000gn/T/pip-record-kij0gfeh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It once says `boost-python` and once `boost_python`

Comment: you just want to install ppaquette-gym-doom? Did you follow [these](https://github.com/ppaquette/gym-doom) instructions? If pip is not working somehow you can also download by hand the repository and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: `cmake` is not a Python program. "`pip install cmake`" makes no sense.

Comment: The note at https://github.com/ppaquette/gym-doom#readme says: "This environment is not maintained anymore, and uses an old version of VizDoom." Your tutorial is likely obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

**You are likely to have more luck building this for Homebrew Python** (in a virtualenv to be able to cleanly remove them later).

**Since this package is no longer maintained, the code may be obsolete and/or unusable.** E.g. after satisfying all the dependencies, I ultimately got a compilation error that suggested `doom-py`'s incompatibility with the latest version of `boost` available in Anaconda.

---

When building things for Anaconda, you need to remember two things:

- Anaconda uses its own compiler toolchain and a set of components and attempts to isolate them from the rest of the system. So **you would need to install any requrements specifically into Anaconda's environment,** not just onto the system.
- **Mixing `conda` with `pip` is always a hazard** because they can't manage each other's packages, so you are bound to break your setup eventually when you get conflicting sets of files (you will be able to recreate it from scratch though). Moreover, Anaconda applies patches to Python and some other packages, so the conda and pip versions of the same package are not always compatible.

  - So `conda` packages should be preferred to `pip` packages -- in the sense that they are much less likely to break things in unpredictable ways.

---

According to https://github.com/ppaquette/gym-doom#dependencies , you need the following dependencies:

> ```
> python-numpy cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libboost-all-dev gcc libsdl2-dev wget unzip git
> ```

Since you are trying to build in another environment -- which the package was not designed for AFAICS, so all bets are off -- **you need to find those dependencies -- they will likely have different names, so you'll need to guess -- in the [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org) and install them into your Anaconda environment (if something is not found there, you'll have to build it from source).**

E.g. (links have install commands):

- boost-python: https://anaconda.org/meznom/boost-python
- sdl2: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sdl2
- others are available from the standard channel

Note that some of the above packages come from different, unofficial channels, so they might be not fully compatible with each other.

While in Homebrew, they are all present in `homebrew-core`:

```
$ for l in cmake zlib libjpeg sdl2 boost; do brew search $l; done
==> Formulae
cmake

==> Casks
homebrew/cask/cmake
==> Formulae
lzlib                                                           zlib                                                            homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-zlib
==> Formulae
libjpeg                                                                                         libjpeg-turbo
==> Formulae
sdl2                            sdl2_gfx                        sdl2_image                      sdl2_mixer                      sdl2_net                        sdl2_ttf
==> Formulae
boost                           boost-build                     boost-python                    boost-python@1.59               boost@1.57                      boost@1.60
boost-bcp                       boost-mpi                       boost-python3                   boost@1.55                      boost@1.59

==> Casks
homebrew/cask/turbo-boost-switcher
```